# Change class according to URL on tabs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML structure of Tabs:

```
<div class="txtabs-content">
<div id="tabs-e-0" class="txtabs-pane active in fade-slide"></div>
<div id="tabs-e-1" class="txtabs-pane fade-slide"></div>
<div id="tabs-e-2" class="txtabs-pane fade-slide"></div>
</div>
```

On page land, the first tab will open. When i set the URL to http://link#tabs-e-1, then the second tab will open.

Is there any way to achieve this using  jQuery, to remove the active class on the first one and add it to the second one?

Comment: `window.location.hash` will return you `#tabs-e-1`

Comment: did you research or tried yourself?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yes, I did read about Hash, but I could not find a way to connect the div ID with the class, and remove the remaining

Comment: I did not downvoted but when you asking  the  question please include your effort alsoin the question , then it is easy to correct your mistakes and you can use the corrected code , otherwise may you got down votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select element id from url with `window.location.hash` and then add class to that element

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.txtabs-pane').removeClass('active in');
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      $(hash).addClass('active in');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.txtabs-pane').removeClass('active in');
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $(hash).addClass('active in');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code (from this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777518/jquery-ui-tabs-update-url-when-clicking-on-a-different-tab)):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {                   
          window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
     }
});
```

Comment: Also, check out this other possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961644/jquery-ui-tabs-change-tab-url-jquery-1-10).